# Jmeter: Stopping a Thread once all other Threads have completed

Tags: jmeter

I have two threads in Jmeter. One the main scripts and the other is handling refreshing the Users Token
This Second one runs every 3 mins and loops forever
The First thread has multi users

this all works great but want to stop the second thread once the first thread has completed the script with all users

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean thread group?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this element to do that by sending a notification from one thread to the other:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have a possibility to detect the "finish" event from the "main" thread group you can pass it to the "refresh" thread group via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)
2. If you don't have such a possibility you can consider adding an [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) which will be checking the number of active threads and in case only 1 thread is left it will mean that the test has ended, example [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) you can use as the condition:

   ```
    ${__groovy((org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getThreadCounts().activeThreads = 1 && vars.getIteration() > 1),)}
   ```

   Once the condition is met you can use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to stop the current thread:

   [image]

Comment: I think the '=' needs to be '=='.
${__groovy((org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getThreadCounts().activeThreads == 1 && vars.getIteration() > 1),)}